# Structure of a Flask app with more than one models.py

Tags: python, flask

I currently have a Flask app with the following structure:

```
deploy/
api/
  customer/
    models.py
  contact/
    models.py
  campaign/
    models.py
  activity/
    models.py
  __init__.py
  database.py
tests/
  test_api.py
```

Because I have so many models, I have split them out into separate files which is causing me issues when I try and initialise my DB.

In each one of my models, I do the following to make Flask-SQLAlchemy's Model call available:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()

class User(db.Model):
...
```

Doing it this way means there's a different `db` object for every model which makes it impossible to initialise my app properly.

How can I structure my project so I can have one `db` object that is used by all my models, tests and my `create_app()` function in `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
  myapp/
    __init__.py
    database.py
    app.py
    model1/
      __init__.py
      models.py
    model2/
      __init__.py
      models.py
```

In the database.py:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

In the various models.py files:

```
from ..database import db

class User(db.Model):
    ...
```

This makes use of [explicit relative imports](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)